# merge two vectors using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have three values below. What I want to do is create a vector the same length as `lookup`, where the `NA` elements are given the value of `replace`, and the rest of the elements are given values in the corresponding position in `data`. E.g.

```
lookup = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, 3, NA)
data = c("user_3", "user_4", "user_6")
replace = "no_user_data"
```

The desired output would then be: `c("no_user_data", "no_user_data", "user_3", "user_4", "no_user_data", "user_6", "no_user_data")`

The key constraint here is I would love to leverage `tidyverse` as much as possible. My current solution looks like this:

```
data <- c(data, replace)
lookup[is.na(lookup)] <- length(data)
data <- data[lookup]
```

which I believe with the help of some `tidyverse` magic could look a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: If you ask me `tidyverse` should be an answer to problems, not a problem in itself. Any particular reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: @mpjdem - I did once see a suggestion to have `add` `subtract` etc functions so you could do `1 %>% add(2)` and get `3` . We haven't reached the peak yet.

Comment: @thelatemail Like `1 %>% \`+\`(2)` (or `1 %>% "+"(2)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::coalesce` function, it's a nice way to [replace missing values](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/) within a vector:

```
dplyr::coalesce(data[lookup], replace)

# [1] "no_user_data" "no_user_data" "user_3"       "user_4"       "no_user_data"
# [6] "user_6"       "no_user_data"
```

Comment: `pmax(data[lookup], replace, na.rm=TRUE)` in base R.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `replace` from `base R`

```
replace(data[lookup], is.na(lookup), replace)
#[1] "no_user_data" "no_user_data" "user_3"       "user_4"       "no_user_data"
#[6] "user_6"       "no_user_data"
```